# How to execute sql file with mysql_connector in C

Tags: sql, mysql, c, linux, mysql-connector

I just want to execute an SQL file in a mysql server using C language.

I tried the command 'source' like it :

`mysql_query(conn, "source path/to/your/file.sql")`

but i found that source wasn't possible with mysql_connector.

So then i tried to read the file in buf and give it to `mysql_query()`

Here's my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

size_t get_file_size(char *path);

int main() {

    /* Declaration */

    MYSQL *conn;
    char username[] = "user";
    char passwd[] = "user";
    char host[] = "localhost";
    char database[] = "";
    char sql_file_path[] = "./db.sql";
    char *sql_file;
    size_t sql_file_sz;
    FILE *sql_fs;

    /* Initialisation */

    sql_file_sz = get_file_size(sql_file_path);
    sql_file = (char *)calloc(sql_file_sz, sizeof(char));
    sql_fs = fopen(sql_file_path, "r");
    if (!sql_fs)
    {
        perror("Error : ");
        goto FatalError;
    }
    fread(sql_file, sql_file_sz, 1, sql_fs);
    if (ferror(sql_fs))
    {
        perror("Error : ");
        goto FatalError;
    }

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    
    if (conn == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : mysql_init() failed\n");
        goto FatalError;
    }
    
    // Connecting to mysql server
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, host, username, passwd, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : mysql_real_connect() failed\n");
        goto FatalError;
    }
    printf("Connected.\n");

    if (mysql_query(conn, sql_file) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : mysql_query() failed : %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        goto FatalError;
    }

    /* Leaving */

    mysql_close(conn);
    fclose(sql_fs);
    free(sql_file);
    
    printf("Exit success.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

FatalError:

    if (conn)
        mysql_close(conn);
    if (sql_fs)
        fclose(sql_fs);
    if (sql_file)
        free(sql_file);

    printf("Exit with failure.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/* 
    Return file size.

    On error, return -1;
*/
size_t get_file_size(char *path)
{
    size_t sz;
    FILE *fp;
    
    fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("Error : ");
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return sz;
}
```

And the "db.sql" file :

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS vacance;

CREATE DATABASE vacance;

USE vacance;

CREATE TABLE Village (
    CodeVillage int,
    NomVillage varchar(30),
    Situation varchar(30)
);
```

When I execute the sql file with the mysql-server shell it works.
But with the C code i have this error :

```
Connected.
Error : mysql_query() failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE vacance;

USE vacance;

CREATE TABLE Village (
    CodeVillage i' at line 3
Exit with failure
```

Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: By default, [`mysql_query()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-query.html) expects its second argument to be a string _"consist of a single SQL statement without a terminating semicolon (;) or \g"_. [3.6.3 Multiple Statement Execution Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)